# Getting Group by right in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, subquery

I have a table which has data and history.

| Date (d/m/y) | fieldId (int) | metaId (int) | Value (Currency) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2/1/2020 | 1 | 3 | 1234 |
| 3/1/2020 | 1 | 3 | 1233 |
| 4/1/2020 | 1 | 3 | 1200 |
| 1/1/2020 | 2 | 3 | 1666 |
| 3/1/2020 | 2 | 3 | 1555 |

from the above table if I perform a query :

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE fieldId IN( 1,2);
```

I should only get :

```
| 4/1/2020     | 1             | 3            | 1200             |
| 3/1/2020     | 2             | 3            | 1555             |
```

I know I will have to use a subquery to return only the latest data, but I am unable to work it out, Can someone help, please.

Comment: Try using the `row_number()` function...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `ROW_NUMBER()` we can try:

```sql
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES *
FROM yourTable
WHERE fieldId IN (1, 2)
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY fieldId ORDER BY Date DESC);
```